# Attachment Download from Gmail by NodeJS

Tags: node.js, axios, gmail, gmail-api

I have an Automation script based on NodeJS which fetches the data from Gmail. But my attachment which is a PDF, its content is getting converted into strings when my code is downloaded in my local folder. Any suggestions to fix this issue will be very helpful.

Here is my function for attachment download which will always be PDF.

```
function downloadAttachment(attachmentId, filename, messageId, callback) {
    axios.get(`https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/${messageId}/attachments/${attachmentId}`, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access_token}`,
        },
    })
        .then(response => {
            fs.writeFileSync(filename, Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64'));
            console.log(`Attachment saved locally: ${filename}`);
            callback();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error downloading attachment:', error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Verified its not working.   I tried adding responseEncoding: 'binary', it didnt help.  This is strange.

Answer (score 0):

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this case, `responseType: "arraybuffer"` is used.

```js
function downloadAttachment(attachmentId, filename, messageId, callback) {
  axios
    .get(
      `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/${messageId}/attachments/${attachmentId}`,
      {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access_token}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      
      // --- I modified the below script.
      const str = new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(response.data));
      const { data } = JSON.parse(str);
      fs.writeFileSync(filename, Buffer.from(data, "base64"));
      // ---
      
      console.log(`Attachment saved locally: ${filename}`);
      callback();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error downloading attachment:", error);
    });
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this case, `responseType: "json"` is used. When `responseType: "json"` is used, the script becomes simple a little.

```js
function downloadAttachment(attachmentId, filename, messageId, callback) {
  axios
    .get(
      `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/${messageId}/attachments/${attachmentId}`,
      {
        responseType: "json",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access_token}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then(({ data: { data } }) => {
      fs.writeFileSync(filename, Buffer.from(data, "base64"));
      console.log(`Attachment saved locally: ${filename}`);
      callback();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error downloading attachment:", error);
    });
}
```

- When I tested this modified script, I confirmed that the attachment file could be downloaded.
- The data decoded from the array buffer is an object like `{"size": 123, "data": "base64 data"}`. So, in order to save the data as a file, it is required to decode the base64 data. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: users.messages.attachments.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments/get)